# SDK download links for Blackberry, Android and Symbian

Tags: android, blackberry, simulator

I am looking for the sdk links of Blackberry, Android and Symbians mobiles, so that I can make applications on these platforms.

Comment: If you cannot make a more specific question than this, I suggest you start by googling for "sdk blackberry", "sdk android", "sdk symbian" etc. When you run into a real problem, please come back here and ask us.

Comment: for android you can find from developer.android.com

Comment: This is a horrid question.... All of these links are available as the first links in google if you search for "platform SDK download"

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find the SDK's and documentation to those platforms by googling them.

[Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

[BlackBerry SDK](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/)

[Symbian SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Library/Tools_and_downloads/Other/Symbian_SDKs/)

Also if you want to learn more about J2EE please check this comprehensive Java EE 6 Tutorial from oracle, [by clicking here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf).

Hope it helps!